# TSQL - Split and Concat string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Code:

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[Id],[FirstName],[LastName]' ;
```

Desired Output:

```
[T1].[Id] = [T2].[Id] AND [T1].[FirstName] = [T2].[FirstName] AND [T1].[LastName] = [T2].[LastName]
```

Goal:

To split the string at the comma and turn it into a JOIN ON clause. So "[Id]" would turn into "[T1].[Id] = [T2].[Id]" - and if there are more tha one columns (comma delimted), it would append those fields in the original order. Please refer to the "Desired Output" for better understanding. I can use STRING_SPLIT to split the values, but not sure how to stuff them the way I need..

Comment: Yuck!!! Delimited data is a mess to work with. And in your case is forcing you to use dynamic sql. This kind of thing has a pretty bad code smell that indicate there are some serious problems in the design.

Comment: Does it have to be done this way?

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot do this. At best, you would have to parse the list out and turn it into a table, then process the rows of the table to generate dynamic sql that you could then use the sp_executesql tactic inside the sproc. This is ugly. Surely there must be another way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you do this in the outside app (c#, python, whatever). Tell us more about what your actually trying to do, not the problem you've hit with this awkward solution that has been devised

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It has to be done inside sql. I'm currently in process of querying Change Tracking data for many tables. Change Tracking tables needs to join with the original table on PKeys. The above variable is an example of it. So I'm trying to create a FX where I can pass in the PKeys and it would spit out the ON clause for the join (T1 = Change Table and T2 = Original Table). The queries are dynamic sql so I would be just concatenating the output into it for each query.

Comment: If this isn't an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) I don't know what is. This sounds like a really brittle and overly complicated design. Have you looked at Change Data Capture? It can track data changes without having to reinvent the wheel. Are you really trying to build a function to receive a delimited list of column names and spit back a join? This is basic string manipulation that should not include delimited values. If anything a table valued function, or even better, a totally different approach.

Comment: Do you really need varchar(max) here? Do you envision ever passing more than 8,000 characters?

Comment: I don't see the PKeys (@ColumnNames) length to exceed 50, 100 max - but unlikely. We already have a FX that returns a PKeys string in that format for whatever table we specify. I'm trying to utilize that FX by taking its output and manipulate it into the "ON" clause for all CHANGE TRACKING queries (instead of writing each ON clause manually.

Comment: You would be FAR better off writing out queries instead of querying data to write dynamic queries. Trying to take shortcuts in writing code is going to lead to performance problems for the users every single time they do anything. Suck it up and write your queries.

Comment: haha... dang it! :(

Comment: If you want something to write out the SQL query for you given a comma-delimited string of column names, I suggest you use a high-level scripting language to do it, like Perl or Python. While you could do it in SQL, why would you want to when other languages can do it much more easily?

Comment: What you're saying makes sense. I would totally create a separate project to do this one task, but this is for my employer and it is more likely that they'll always have a sql dev, but no perl/python dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an answer to your question. If I understand you correctly and you want to generate a `JOIN` clause for your dynamic statement, you have at least two options:

- use `STRING_SPLIT()`, but if you want to *"... append those fields in the original order ..."*, this is not an option, because the order of the substrings is not guaranteed
- transform input string into a valid `JSON` and use `OPENJSON()`.

T-SQL using STRING_SPLIT():

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[Id],[FirstName],[LastName]'
DECLARE @join nvarchar(max) = N''
SELECT @join = STUFF(
   (
   SELECT 
      CONCAT(
         N' AND [t1].',
         s.[value],
         N'=[t2].',
         s.[value]
      )
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ColumnNames, N',') s
   FOR XML PATH('')
   ),
   1, 5, N'')
PRINT @join
```

T-SQL using OPENJSON():

```
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[Id],[FirstName],[LastName]'
DECLARE @join nvarchar(max) = N''
SELECT @join = STUFF(
   (
   SELECT 
      CONCAT(
         N' AND [t1].',
         j.[value],
         N'=[t2].',
         j.[value]
      )
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(@ColumnNames, 'json'), N',', N'","'), N'"]')) j
   ORDER BY [key]
   FOR XML PATH('')
   ),
   1, 5, N'')
PRINT @join
```

Output:

```
[t1].[Id]=[t2].[Id] AND [t1].[FirstName]=[t2].[FirstName] AND [t1].[LastName]=[t2].[LastName]
```

Comment: These are fantastic approaches. I especially like the OPENJSON (never seen such approach - STUFF w/ JSON) THANK YOU for sharing (and options w/ pros/cons). Cheers

Comment: @007 I'm glad I helped.